# Oracle apex dynamic print report query

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, xsl-fo, oracle-apex-5

I want to make calls to print report query dynamically from my oracle apex page.So I used the code

```
htp.init;
owa_util.redirect_url('f?p=' || v('APP_ID') || ':0:' || v('SESSION')||':PRINT_REPORT=RND');
apex_application.stop_apex_engine;
```

But it does not works all the time. Data is generated in the table on which report query is written. But the query just generates a blank layout. I use xsl-fo for my report layout. Anybody have some solution?

Comment: Since this question is quite niche, you may have better luck on [the Oracle APEX forum](https://community.oracle.com/community/database/developer-tools/application_express)